# React-Native 62.2 code image upload Error : network error

Tags: react-native

I am using React-Native two days back After React-Native version upgrading to 0-62.2, I encountered many problems.
Among them important one is image upload  error getting [Error:Network error ]
Before upgrading the React-native my code is working fine

### Below code is working fine for me for multiple image upload before upgrading to React-Native 0.62.2 but now i am getting [Error: Network error]

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      uploadPercentage: 0,
    }
  }

  // upload Files upload_Files = async () => {
  upload_File() {
    
    if (this.validate_Fields()) {
      const { image, images, files, description, userId, size } = this.state;
      console.log('AddPost Screen : upload_File:', 'userId:', userId, 'Files:', files, 'description:', description)
      // this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

      if (this.state.type === 'image/jpeg') {
       
        console.log('AddPost Screen : upload_ files :', files);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('user_id', userId);
        formData.append('description', description);
        // formData.append('files[]', files);
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          formData.append('files[]', {
            name: files[i].path.split('/').pop(),
            type: files[i].mime,
            uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? files[i].path : files[i].path.replace('file://', ''),
          });
        }


        // upload percentage progress bar  ******************************************************
        const options = {
          onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
            let percent = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total)
            console.log(`${loaded}kb of ${total}kb | ${percent}%`);

            if (percent < 100) {
              this.setState({ uploadPercentage: percent })
            }
          }
        }


        axios.post(API_URL + '/fileuploadapi/uploadPost', formData, options, {
          headers: { "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" }
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.status)));


          // upload percentage progress 
          this.setState({ uploadPercentage: 100 }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.setState({ uploadPercentage: 0 })
            }, 1000);
          })


          this.cleanupImages();

          Alert.alert('Upload Post Successfully');
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.cleanupImages();

          Alert.alert('image Upload Post Failed  , Try again !');
        });
 
     }
   }
}



  // clear files data 
  cleanupImages() {
    
    this.setState({
      description: '',
      image: null,
      images: null,
      // video: '',
      files: '',
      uploadPercentage: 0,
    })
    ImagePicker.clean().then(() => {
      console.log('removed tmp images from tmp directory');
    }).catch(error => {
      alert(error);
    });
  }
```

If anyone know the solution please let me know ...

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution for the React-Native 62.2 upgrading error for image upload Error

[Error: network error]

Just remove the file   "ReactNativeFlipper.java" from   debug/java folder 
File Location : 
android/app/src/debug/java/com/appname/ReactNativeFlipper.java